# How do I make my discord bot copy and paste someone's message in python?

Tags: discord.py

I am trying to make a command that has an interaction like this:

User: p.poesia (text) @user
Bot: *(text copied)*
@user, 2021

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please include your code, approaches and errors you face. You may also take a look at [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I dont know how to make the necessary code for it, that is why i am asking here

Answer (score 0):

Please consider reading the [discord.py](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en) documentation.

This is the basic code I made for you to run it.

```
@client.command()
async def poesia(ctx, text):
      await ctx.send(text + str(ctx.author))
```